# How to add dynamic sizes to react-icon?

Tags: reactjs

```js
  const handleLeftIcon = () => {
    if (leftIcon)
      return (
        <div className="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3 pointer-events-none">
          {cloneElement(leftIcon as any, {
            ...leftIconProps,
            className:{`${classScale[scale].icon}`}
          })}
        </div>
      );
    return <></>;
  };
```

it shows

> This expression is not callable.
> Type '{}' has no call signatures.

Comment: which line the error is thrown from?